# "IApplicationBuilder" does not contain a definition for "MapSignalR"

Tags: signalr, asp.net-core-mvc, visual-studio-2017, asp.net-core-middleware

I'm trying to register SignalR on the Startup class of a ASP.NET Core project. When I try to call `app.MapSignalR()` for registering and enabling SignalR on the project, it gives me:

> "IApplicationBuilder" does not contain a definition for "MapSignalR"...

Any ideia why? How to properly register signalR? Someone else dealing the same problem?

Tried to install *Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OwinSelfHost* and *Microsoft.Owin* but no success ;(

- *Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR 2.2.1 and it's dependencies are all installed*
- *Target framework is set to .NET 4.5.2*
- *The code was auto-generated by VS2017*

Were follows my Startup.cs class file *(it was auto-generated by VS)*:

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using WebApplication1.Data;
using WebApplication1.Models;
using WebApplication1.Services;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
                .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true);

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                // For more details on using the user secret store see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=532709
                builder.AddUserSecrets<Startup>();
            }

            builder.AddEnvironmentVariables();
            Configuration = builder.Build();
        }

        public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            // Add framework services.
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

            services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

            services.AddMvc();

            // Add application services.
            services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, AuthMessageSender>();
            services.AddTransient<ISmsSender, AuthMessageSender>();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
            loggerFactory.AddDebug();

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
                app.UseBrowserLink();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            }

            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseIdentity();

            app.MapSignalR(); // "IApplicationBuilder" does not contain a definition for "MapSignalR"...

            // Add external authentication middleware below. To configure them please see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=532715

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add another `using` statement.  Based on this sample: https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR-Client-Cpp/blob/c152e53fc27d4a7670baa3a7953b99edeab88be5/samples/SignalRServer/Startup.cs, try this:

```
 using Owin;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @RonC! It solved! have added the *using Owin* directive also registered SignalR using a method with a name different than *Configuration* to avoid the name conflict with the *Configuration* auto-generated property by VS ;)

Comment: Cool. Which of the using statements was it?  I can edit my answer and then you can accept the updated answer.

Comment: I have used the *using Owin* directive @RonC. The *using Microsoft.Owin* is not required for this goal. Thanks!